# Data loader on custom object, Object ID not available in field mapping

Tags: data-loader, security, fields, data

Colleague has the same 'Admin' profile as me.

If I try to update data via the data loader I see all fields, if he tries he can not see the custom object id but can access the object?

Note this is not an external ID or anything.  I have read about fields not on layouts wont show but this is the ID which to my knowledge cant be added to layouts anyway.  Also I am unaware of any field permissions regarding record ids either.

UPDATE:
So I go

1. Dataloader
2. Update records
3. Select custom object
4. Then get the field mappings as per this image:
   [image]

However my colleague does not see the ID in the top section IE the available SF fields to map to.

Any suggestions thanks?

Comment: do you try to populate ID on insert ?

Comment: Apologies this is an update.  So we have ids of records in that object and want to update the records.  But the id field is not available from the field mapper.

Comment: Hard to visualize, some screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of what your colleague sees when tries to map the fields in the data loader.

Comment: Is `Admin` profile a System Administrator profile or a custom Profile. If the latter, you may have a permission set that extends Update access to this Object whereas your colleague does not. Check CRUD permissions for profile Admin

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you accidentally clicked insert? I was just pulling my hair out on the same issue and realized I clicked Insert instead of Update.

Answer (score 0):

In no specific order...

- Is this a normal custom object or maybe something that comes from a managed package / needs separate license that you have but your colleague doesn't.
- Do you guys have same preferred language set? If the object was translated in Translation Workbench he might see the Id but under different label
- Can you run this as both users: `System.debug(Account.Id.getDescribe().isAccessible());` (use your custom object's API name). If you get different results but have identical profiles - there might be a permission set that grants you extra access... That'd be weird though, I imagine ID to be always accessible, it's not even one of checkboxes you can tick in Profile...
- what if he skips this step completely? Prepare the Data Loader's mapping file (extension is *.sdl if I recall correctly), give it to him to try loading it and running the update. Maybe he'll get a meaningful error.